# How to install ActiveMQ Artemis as a Windows service?

Tags: windows-service, activemq

The title is a bit missleading since I know how to install artemis as a windows service, according to the documentation one just has to run

```
artemis-service.exe install
```

This does not work for me. I tried to install and run the service with ActiveMQ Artemis versions 2.31 and 2.29. For both versions, running the service produces the following log in `artemis-service.wrapper.log`

```
2023-10-23 10:19:50,116 DEBUG - Starting WinSW in the service mode
2023-10-23 10:19:50,147 INFO  - Starting %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe  -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-artemis-2.31.0\lib\artemis-boot.jar" "-Dartemis.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-artemis-2.31.0" -Dartemis.instance=C:\ArtemisBroker -Ddata.dir=C:\ArtemisBroker\data -Dartemis.instance.etc=C:\ArtemisBroker\etc -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\ArtemisBroker\etc\login.config -Dhawtio.disableProxy=true -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.offline="true" -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=file:/C:/ArtemisBroker/etc/jolokia-access.xml org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis run 
2023-10-23 10:19:50,178 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
```

and the following warning pops up:

[image]

The only source giving some kind of hint is the Windows event log with the following entry:

[image]

```
Service cannot be started. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at winsw.Util.ProcessHelper.StartProcessAndCallbackForExit(Process processToStart, String executable, String arguments, Dictionary`2 envVars, String workingDirectory, Nullable`1 priority, ProcessCompletionCallback callback, Boolean redirectStdin, LogHandler logHandler, Boolean hideWindow)
   at winsw.WrapperService.StartProcess(Process processToStart, String arguments, String executable, LogHandler logHandler, Boolean redirectStdin)
   at winsw.WrapperService.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

I checked all the paths in the executed command but everything seems fine.

The only thing I noticed are the entries

```xml
<startargument>-Djolokia.policyLocation=%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI%/jolokia-access.xml</startargument>
```

and

```xml
<env name="ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI" value="file:/C:/ArtemisBroker/etc/"/>
```

in `artemis-service.xml`, which then gets resolved to

```
-Djolokia.policyLocation=file:/C:/ArtemisBroker/etc//jolokia-access.xml org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis
```

which seems kind of wrong, but changing this (removing one `/`) does not change anything.

How to resolve this?

Comment: If an application fails due to a file not found, and the application does not specify the file name/location that is actually failing to open, you will need to use a tool such as Sysinternals Procmon to perform a trace and identify the offending file path. Also, `which seems kind of wrong` is imprecise. You should be able to... Use the path...to...Open the file.  And you need to know the actual path that is failing, not just a jumbled composite of multiple values before translation.

Comment: I could have highlighted that "it seems kind of wrong" because there is a double slash in the file path. I will try Procmon, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greg's comment I could figure out the problem.
Using Sysinternals process monitor, after some filtering I found the following entries:

[image]

This means, the service startup couldn't even find the java executable for startup. The paths show that the environment variable `%JAVA_HOME%` in fact can not be found (and the program scans PATH plugging in the subpath string).

I was surprised by that since I was pretty sure to have set the variable - my mistake was that I set it as a user variable and not a system variable. Apparently, windows starts the service under an other user as the user I'm logged in as, so the variable cannot be found.

Setting `%JAVA_HOME%` as a system environment variable resolved this issue.